# I can't save changes of settings of an Omega subtheme. Problem just happens in remote server

Tags: theming

I can't save changes of settings of an Omega subtheme in **admin/appearance/settings/omega_subtheme_2**

I get no error message. The changes are not saved at all.

This problem just happens in remote server. In my local server works just fine.

I guess it could be a folder or file permission problem. I already set the permission of **site/all/themes/omega subtheme 2** folder and all its content to 777. But the problem persist.

Comment: Is your remote server pointing at the correct database?

Comment: yes, if you mean the settings of 'Database configuration format:' in sites/default/settings.php (line 180)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this thread may answer your question: http://drupal.org/node/1388196

for some it is a suPHP request.max_vars and  post.max_vars issue